# Regexp Javascript replacing

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function example(){
   var quantity = "http://www.example.com/index.php?brandid=b%123&quantity=20";
   quantity = quantity.replace(-what regular expression should i user-, "quantity=50");
}
```

i want to replace only the `quantity=20` to `quantity=50` in link. but i have tried some of the regular expression such as：

```
replace(/quantity=[^\d]/g,"quantity=50")；
replace(/quantity=[^0-9]/g,"quantity=50")；
```

so i would like to have some help from expertise in regular expression to help me =) thanks

Comment: Don't use the caret `^` in the [0-9] part.  The caret there says to find anything *but* what follows.  Instead, try this:  `[0-9]+`, as it will match any number one or more times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
replace(/quantity=[\d]+/g,"quantity=50")
```

Comment: That won't work. You either have to put the `+` outside of the brackets or--better still--not use the brackets at all. Everything inside the character class represents *one* character.

Comment: What about `?some_other_quantity=5&quantity=9`?

Comment: thank you !! =) i have solve my problem.... it was breaking my head in the early morning =(

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could do it. It will only ever work with the query string, not the entire URL.

```
function example(){
   var quantity = 'http://www.example.com/index.php?brandid=b%123&quantity=20',
       a = document.createElement('a');

    a.href = quantity;

    a.search = a.search.replace(/([?&;]quantity=)\d+/, '$150');;

   return a.href;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urQaF/).

Comment: anchor.search will begin with a `?` so that should probably be `a.search = a.search.replace(/([&^;\?]quantity=)[\d\.]+/, '$150');` Added a decimal too, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

```
replace(/[?&]quantity=\d+([&]?)/g,"$1quantity=50$2")；
```

try this ^

---

```
([?&])
```

group together either symbol **'?'** or **'&'** (one and only one char) as the group named $1

```
\d+
```

find at least one **digit**
and find the longest consecutive string of **digits** if there is >1 digits

```
([&]?)
```

group together either **empty string** (if at the end) or **'&'** as the group named $2

'?' means match zero or one time

by grouping a group of match in ()...()....() and then use it in the result as $1,$2,$3... you can do search and replace plus many more complex operations.